# Search for files that have a common naming convention

Tags: c#, filenames, uniqueidentifier

I have a folder, full of 38,000+ .pdf files.  I was not the genius to put them all into one folder, but I now have the task of separating them.  The files that are of value to us, all have the same basic naming convention, for example:

123456_20130604_NEST_IV
456789_20120209_VERT_IT

What I'm trying to do, if possible, is search the folder for only those files with that particular naming convention.  As in, search only for files that have 6 digits, an underscore, and then 8 digits followed by another underscore.  Kind of like `*****_********`.  I've searched online but I haven't had much luck.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Try `Directory.GetFiles` and `Regex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^\d{6}_\d{8}_", RegexOptions.Compiled);

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath)
                          .Where(path => regex.Match(Path.GetFileName(path)).Success)
                          .ToArray();
```

`files` would contain paths to a files, that match criteria.

For my example `C:\Temp\123456_20130604_NEST_IV 456789_20120209_VERT_IT.pdf`, which I've added beforehand.

---

As a bonus, here is [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx) script to do this (assuming you are in the correct folder, otherwise use `gc "C:\temp"` instead of `dir`):

```
dir | Where-Object {$_ -match "^\d{6}_\d{8}_"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

? - single character
* - multiple characters

So, I would say use ?????? _ ???????? _ ???? _ ??.* to get all your files
You can use move or copy command from a command prompt to do that.
If you want to do advanced searches such as pattern matching, use windows grep: http://www.wingrep.com/

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with regular expressions? If not, they are a generalized way to search for strings of a special format. I see you tagged your question with C# so assuming you are writing a C# script you might try the .NET regular expression module.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

If you are a beginner, you may want to start here.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to handle this. What I like to do is to divide work into different steps with clear output/data in each step. Hence I would tackle this in the following way (since this seems easier for me instead of writing a master program in c# that does everything):

1. Open windows command prompt (start/run/cmd), navigate to correct
   folder and then "dir *.pdf > pdf_files.txt". This would give you a
   file containing all pdf-files inside the specific folder.
2. open up the txt-file (pdf_files.txt) in Notepad++ and then press "ctrl + f
   (find)" activate radio button "regular expressions"
3. type: `[0-9]{6}_[0-9]{8}_.*\.pdf` and press `"Find all in current document"`
4. Copy results and save to new .txt-file
5. Now you have a text file containing all pdf-files that you can do what you want with (create a c# program that parses the files and move them depending on their name or whatever)